# How to determine which type of update is in progress?

Tags: java, android, google-play, in-app-update

I am implementing android's In-App update. **The problem I am facing is when the user kills application during app update and reopens it**.

**Need To Do:**

On app reopen, I need to show install state according to the type of update, but there seems no way to differentiate the type of update going on.

If install state is `InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED` and update type is Flexible, I need to show a Snackbar to the user stating that update has been downloaded with install action.
And if update type is Immediate and update is in progress, I need to continue with google Immediate update screen.

**What is happening**

I have added this code in my activity's onStart callback. When update type Flexible is in progress(not downloaded), it is going in else case every time, getting update availability `UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS`.

```
public void checkIfUpdateInProgress() {

        mAppUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo().addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {

mAppUpdateInfo = appUpdateInfo;
            if (appUpdateInfo.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED) {
                showUpdateDownloadedSnackbar();
            } else if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability()
                    == UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS) {
                requestImmediateUpdate();
            }
        });

    }



    public void requestImmediateUpdate() {

        try {
            mAppUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                    // Pass the intent that is returned by 'getAppUpdateInfo()'.
                    mAppUpdateInfo,
                    // Or 'AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE' for flexible updates.
                    AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                    // The current activity making the update request.
                    MyJsActivity.this,
                    // Include a request code to later monitor this update request.
                    REQUEST_CODE_APP_UPDATE_IMMEDIATE);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```